# Disabling download attachments to guest users

Tags: community, security, attachment, guest-user

I would like to disable the possibility to download and read attachments to guest users of my community by requesting them from `https://<salesforce-url>/community/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=<attach.id>`

Do you know how to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: If they can view it, they can download it no matter what you do

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to do that in Salesforce. There is a similar kind of idea in community [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bp9XAAS), you can upvote that one.

We won't be able to restrict downloading even by using visualforce page, as the user would still be able to download file using the URL as mentioned by you in your question.

Comment: You don't understand my question. I want to make those attachments private.

Comment: Well, that was not something which was mentioned in the original question. Anyhow, I am afraid that making attachment as private is also still not possible in Salesforce. There is an idea for this as well at [this](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Brew) and [this](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrJeAAK) link. Both the ideas are merged, may be you can upvote this one.